# Extracting individual address components from Google geocoder results in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-geocoder

There seems to be some difficulty about getting individual address components out of a JSON Google geocoder result.  For example, I want to get county names based on addresses.  Could someone please explain why, for example, this code doesn't work?

```
function county(){
  var geo = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode('address');
  for (var i=0; i<geo.results.address_components.length; i++)
    for (var j=0; j<geo.results.address_components[i].types.length; j++)
      if (geo.results.address_components[i].types[j]=="administrative_area_level_2")
        var county = geo.results.address_components[i].long_name;
}
```

I know this is overly simplistic, but it can't even recognize the `results.address_components`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bill! No need to caveat your question, this wasn't a stupid one at all (though those are fine here too, easy points for answerers).  For future reference, it'll be easier for the community to troubleshoot if you can provide reproducible code (i.e. use a real address instead of 'address') and can also save time if you copy in the error message. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Logger object to look at intermediary data like this:

```
Logger.log(geo)
```

You'll see something like this in the view menu, under logs:

`{results=[{address_components=[{long_name=Address, short_name=Address, types=[point_of_interest, establishment]}, {long_name=Madrid, short_name=Madrid, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=Madrid, short_name=M, types=[administrative_area_level_2, political]}, {long_name=Community of Madrid, short_name=Community of Madrid, types=[administrative_area_level_1, political]}, {long_name=Spain, short_name=ES, types=[country, political]}, {long_name=28039, short_name=28039, types=[postal_code]}], formatted_address=Address, 28039 Madrid, Spain, types=[hospital, point_of_interest, establishment], geometry={viewport={southwest={lng=-3.708366880291502, lat=40.44598801970851}, northeast={lng=-3.705668919708498, lat=40.44868598029151}}, location_type=APPROXIMATE, location={lng=-3.7070179, lat=40.447337}}}, {address_components=[{long_name=Address:, short_name=Address:, types=[point_of_interest, establishment]}, {long_name=Pineville, short_name=Pineville, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=1, Charlotte, short_name=1, Charlotte, types=[administrative_area_level_3, political]}, {long_name=Mecklenburg County, .........`

If you run

```
function myFunction() {
   var geo = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode('1600 pennsylvania ave, washington, dc');
   Logger.log(geo.results[0].address_components);
}

myFunction();
```

You can see the components in the log, it will look like this:

`{long_name=1600, short_name=1600, types=[street_number]}, {long_name=President's Park, short_name=President's Park, types=[establishment]}, {long_name=Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, short_name=Pennsylvania Ave NW, types=[route]}, {long_name=Washington, short_name=Washington, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=District of Columbia, short_name=DC, types=[administrative_area_level_1, political]}, {long_name=United States, short_name=US, types=[country, political]}, {long_name=20500, short_name=20500, types=[postal_code]}`

In this case, none of components are "administrative_area_level_2", but in your case they might be.

You should also consider using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Hopefully this will help you nail down what the more specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Aaron and Micah's answers, you're really close, just mostly need to select the first result. [`geocode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder#geocode(String)) produces an array of results, but if you're geocoding a single address, grabbing the first will work. Their answer uses the White House address, which appears not to have a county, but using Google HQ (as Google tends to do in examples) produces a valid result.

Here's a generic function for selecting any component of the [geocoding responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses), also leveraging `indexOf` to check if the desired component is in the `types` array (saving a `for` loop):

```js
function getAddressComponent(address, component) {
  var geo = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
  var resultComponents = geo.results[0].address_components;
  for (var i = 0; i < resultComponents.length; i++) {
     if (resultComponents[i].types.indexOf(component) > -1) {
       return resultComponents[i].long_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Testing with `Logger`, we get the correct value of 'Santa Clara County':

```js
function getAddressComponent_test() {
  var address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA';
  Logger.log(getAddressComponent(address, 'administrative_area_level_2'));
}
```